# USB/Serial communication with Netty

Tags: usb, serial-port, ipc, named-pipes, netty

In our organisation, we implemented our own protocol over UDP and TCP to let external devices connected to the Internet exchange messages with a server that we developed using Netty (indeed!).

For testing purpose, we would like to connect those devices directly to our computers through USB/serial interface (we did not choose the serial communication library yet). We would also like to deploy/port the embedded software we developed for our devices on our computer to simulate the devices and to connect directly to our server using a named pipe for example (IPC).

In the [Architecture Overview documentation of Netty](http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/#architecture.5), you claim that we could use *Netty* as well for such serial communication:

> "*Also, you are even able to take advantage of new transports which aren't yet written (such as serial port communication transport), again by replacing just a couple lines of constructor calls. Moreover, you can write your own transport by extending the core API.*"

Is anyone somewhere already developed such implementation in Netty or does someone else plan to do such implementation? I am also wondering if Netty is really well-suited for that since the Channel interface and many other ones use a SocketAddress to bind/connect to a peer?

Thank you for your suggestions, advices!

Comment: I have same requirement - Use Serial communication with Netty. Were you able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you may be able to use the new iostream package for that. All you need here is an InputStream and Outputstream. See [1]

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/iostream

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement such a solutions. I have not meet problems with binding with SocketAddress.

---

I’m posting my implementation of USB connection with Netty.

Serial communication is quite simillar, I'm not posting it for brevity. However I am happy to add it as well if anyone needs it.

Here is base class for connection. A ChannelHandler shall be implemented according to communication needs.

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPromise;

import java.net.SocketAddress;

public abstract class ConnectorImpl {

    protected ChannelHandler handler;
    protected Bootstrap bootstrap;
    protected ChannelFuture channelFuture;

    public ChannelFuture connect() throws Exception {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(getSocketAddress()).sync();
        }
        return channelFuture.channel().closeFuture();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            return channelFuture.channel().isOpen();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            channelFuture.channel().close().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    protected ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter createOutgoingErrorHandler() {
        return new ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
                final ChannelFutureListener channelFutureListener = future -> {
                    if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                        future.channel().close();
                    }
                };
                promise.addListener(channelFutureListener);
                ctx.write(msg, promise);
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract SocketAddress getSocketAddress();
}
```

An extensions of that connector for needed type of connection together with Channel implementations is needed.

USB connector:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler;
import javax.usb.UsbDevice;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class UsbConnectorImpl extends ConnectorImpl {

    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 60;
    private final UsbDevice usbDevice;

    public UsbConnectorImpl(UsbChannelHandler handler, UsbDevice usbDevice) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.usbDevice = usbDevice;
        this.bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                .channel(getChannelClass())
                .group(getLoop())
                .handler(getChannelInitializer());
    }

    public EventLoopGroup getLoop() {
        return new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    }

    Class<UsbAsyncChannel> getChannelClass() {
        return UsbAsyncChannel.class;
    }

    ChannelInitializer<Channel> getChannelInitializer() {
        return new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

            @Override
            public void initChannel(@SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems") Channel ch) {
                ch.pipeline()
                        .addLast("Generic encoder", new RequestEncoder())
                        .addLast("Decoder", new ResponseDecoder())
                        .addLast("Read timeout handler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                        .addLast("Outgoing Error Handler", createOutgoingErrorHandler())
                        .addLast("Card Reader handler", handler);
            }
        };
    }

    public SocketAddress getSocketAddress() {
        return new UsbDeviceAddress(usbDevice);
    }
}
```

USB Channel:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.FileRegion;
import io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;

import javax.usb.UsbConfiguration;
import javax.usb.UsbDevice;
import javax.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import javax.usb.UsbInterface;
import javax.usb.UsbPipe;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeDataEvent;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeErrorEvent;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.Pipe;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public abstract class UsbChannel extends AbstractNioByteChannel {

    protected static final byte INTERFACE_BULK_PIPES = (byte) 1;
    private static final AtomicInteger READ_TASK_COUNTER = new AtomicInteger();
    private final UsbChannelConfig config;
    protected UsbPipe outPipe = null;
    protected UsbPipe inPipe = null;
    private UsbDevice usbDevice;
    private UsbDeviceAddress deviceAddress;
    private UsbInterface usbInterface;

    public UsbChannel() throws IOException {
        super(null, Pipe.open().source());
        config = new UsbChannelConfig(this);
    }

    @Override
    public UsbChannelConfig config() {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() {
        return usbDevice != null;
    }

    @Override
    protected ChannelFuture shutdownInput() {
        try {
            doClose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pipeline().fireExceptionCaught(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected abstract ReadTask createReadTask();

    protected void invokeRead() {
        ReadTask task = createReadTask();
        task.scheduledFuture = eventLoop().schedule(task, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractNioUnsafe newUnsafe() {
        return new UsbUnsafe();
    }

    @Override
    protected long doWriteFileRegion(FileRegion region) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected int doReadBytes(ByteBuf buf) throws Exception {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Pipe.SourceChannel javaChannel() {
        return (Pipe.SourceChannel) super.javaChannel();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean doConnect(SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress) throws Exception {
        UsbDeviceAddress remote = (UsbDeviceAddress) remoteAddress;
        usbDevice = remote.value();

        UsbConfiguration configuration = usbDevice.getActiveUsbConfiguration();
        usbInterface = configuration.getUsbInterface(INTERFACE_BULK_PIPES);
        usbInterface = usbInterface.getActiveSetting();
        usbInterface.claim();

        for (int i = 0; i < usbInterface.getUsbEndpoints().size(); i++) {
            UsbEndpoint endpoint = (UsbEndpoint) usbInterface.getUsbEndpoints().get(i);
            UsbPipe usbPipe = endpoint.getUsbPipe();
            if (endpoint.getDirection() == LibUsb.ENDPOINT_IN) {
                inPipe = usbPipe;
                inPipe.open();
            } else if (endpoint.getDirection() == LibUsb.ENDPOINT_OUT) {
                outPipe = usbPipe;
                outPipe.open();
            }
            if (inPipe != null && outPipe != null) {
                break;
            }
        }

        outPipe.addUsbPipeListener(new UsbPipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void errorEventOccurred(UsbPipeErrorEvent event) {
                pipeline().fireExceptionCaught(event.getUsbException());
            }

            @Override
            public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent event) {
                invokeRead();
            }
        });

        inPipe.addUsbPipeListener(new UsbPipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void errorEventOccurred(UsbPipeErrorEvent event) {
                pipeline().fireExceptionCaught(event.getUsbException());
            }

            @Override
            public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent event) {
                pipeline().fireChannelRead(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(event.getData(), 0, event.getData().length));
            }
        });

        deviceAddress = remote;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFinishConnect() throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public UsbDeviceAddress localAddress() {
        return (UsbDeviceAddress) super.localAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public UsbDeviceAddress remoteAddress() {
        return (UsbDeviceAddress) super.remoteAddress();
    }

    @Override
    protected UsbDeviceAddress localAddress0() {
        return deviceAddress;
    }

    @Override
    protected UsbDeviceAddress remoteAddress0() {
        return deviceAddress;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doBind(SocketAddress localAddress) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDisconnect() throws Exception {
        doClose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doClose() throws Exception {
        try {
            super.doClose();
            javaChannel().close();
        } finally {
            if (inPipe != null) {
                inPipe.close();
                inPipe = null;
            }
            if (outPipe != null) {
                outPipe.close();
                outPipe = null;
            }
            if (usbInterface != null) {
                usbInterface.release();
                usbInterface = null;
            }
            if (usbDevice != null) {
                usbDevice = null;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract static class ReadTask implements Runnable, ChannelFutureListener {

        protected final int id;
        protected ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

        public ReadTask() {
            this.id = READ_TASK_COUNTER.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    private final class UsbUnsafe extends AbstractNioUnsafe {
        @Override
        public void read() {
        }
    }
}
```